# Old projects are not running in new iPhone SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a `UICatlog` project downloaded from apple development library. It was running fine with 3.0 Base SDK, but when I upgrade xCode SDK Version 3.2.3. I am getting an error:

```
error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos3.0'
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Base SDK setting in the Project Info to iPhone Device 4.0.

Comment: I did that, but still it showing the same thing. Showing "Base SDK missing"

Comment: Did you change it for the right configuration? For example if you're running it in Debug, did you change it to 4.0 for Debug in Project Settings? Same for Device vs. Simulator, if you changed it for Device are you running it for Device?

Comment: Yes, my settings are: Active configuration: Debug,  Base SDK: iPhone simulator4.0,   Project format: Xcode 3.2 compatible.

Still not working. Any one tried to run UICatlog on 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you aren't changing the Base SDK for the project and not the current target. The current target base SDK setting will override the project settings.  Also, if you wan't to support older platform versions, make sure you set Deployment target appropriately.